# retina.js for hardcoded css background-images

Tags: javascript, css, background-image, retina.js

i'm using using the css `background-image` attribute to display images. Those images are queried via `ajax`, therefore I know i am supposed to call this:

```
$('img').each(function(){new RetinaImage(this);});
```

after the images are loaded.

It works with images or the `img` tag, but since I need the background-image `url()` attribute to be updated – I am not sure how to do this.

I tried to change the JS to:

```
$('.myBackgroundImgClass').each(function(){new RetinaImage(this);});
```

for the div:

```
<div class="myBackgroundImgClass" style="background-image:url(..someImg.jpg);"></div>
```

but it does not seem to do the job. Any suggestions?
Thanks!